# Apache VirtualHosts - Exclude a single file from URL redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, vhosts

I'm currently redirecting all requests to my Apache server from `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com` -- it works fine but I actually need just ONE file to still be loaded as if it's at `olddomain.com`.

Here's what the important bit looks like now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName olddomain.com
ServerAlias olddomain.com

Redirect / http://newdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I loved this simple `Redirect / http://newdomain.com` solution because it does exactly what I want and is so simple even I can understand it! BUT how do I make an exception so that when someone/something goes to `http://olddomain.com/excludedfile.php`, it loads to the expected domain name? The solutions I've found so far seem to be for mod_rewrite setups. If mod_rewrite is what's required I guess I can live with it but I'd rather not...

**Why I need this:** I just submitted my app to Apple and decided at the last minute that I needed to change the domain name, which breaks one feature of the app because it's relying explicitly on seeing the old domain name -- it doesn't see it anymore because of the changes made to my virtual hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `RedirectMatch` for the regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^((?!.*?excludedfile\.php).*)$ http://newdomain.com$1
```

This change will require you to restart the Apache.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I replaced my `Redirect` line with this and now everything just redirects to the homepage (`http://newdomain.com/` - nothing after the slash).

Comment: Ah yes there was a typo, try updated rule and restart.

Comment: Weird - now when I go to `http://olddomain.com/excludedfile.php` I get a 404 Error... trying to load any other location under `http://olddomain.com` results in an extra // before the file name - `http://olddomain.com/otherfile.php` becomes `http://newdomain.com//otherfile.php`...

Comment: Made another update that will fix the double `//` problem and as you can see it is not redirecting `http://olddomain.com/excludedfile.php` now.

Comment: Hmmmmm... Yeah but I'm still getting the weird 404 error... I guess it may be something else causing the 404 error?

Comment: Right 404 is not because of this rule since rule is just skipping this to redirect to other website.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44757/discussion-between-tylerl-and-anubhava)

Comment: @tylerl: Sorry I have to rush for a meeting, will be available online after an hour.

Comment: For future visitors: The code above is perfect - the double slash issue AND the 404 error were because of my previous bad redirect code and my server requiring a custom DocumentRoot.

Comment: @tylerl: Very nice comment to help out future visitors. I just came back online.